# What is the best data structure to use to save data from an excel file that will then be used to generate a GUI where the data can be edited?

Tags: java, excel

I am currently creating a program that will take an excel spreadsheet and save the cell data in a 2D array. If a cell is empty then an empty string is used. I then generate a GUI using that data. My GUI needs to have input fields where the data can be extracted and used.
The excel spreadsheet has a set amount of columns but can have any amount of rows as well as empty cells.

I was wondering what the best data structure to use to store the data from the excel spreadsheet is that will allow me to edit the data and add new columns/rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to use a library, you might want to have a look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree. Sound solution would have all GUI operations be backed up on the `Workbook` object from POI.

Comment: I'm already using Apache POI to open and retrieve the data from the spreadsheet. I didn't think about editing the current spreadsheet. You may have just made my life 10x easier, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming encryption isn't a concern, why not use a simple `.csv` file?